# How to link opencv static libs via variable ${OpenCV_LIBS} in cmake

Tags: opencv, cmake

I build both shared and static of opencv (**I need all the static and shared version**). Sometime I want to link the static opencv libs via ${OpenCV_LIBS} in cmake. But it doesn't work when I use ${OpenCV_LIBS}. Is there an variable to link opencv static version libs

Comment: You have *different OpenCV installations*: one with shared libs, another with static libs, am I right? If so, just `set(OpenCV_DIR <opencv-install-path>)` to path with static OpenCV installation before `find_package(OpenCV)` call, and variable `OpenCV_LIBS` will contain static libs.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly link the static libs that you want by using (assuming that you have set the system variable `OpenCV_DIR` and want to link the `opencv_core` lib of OpenCV-v2.4.8 under VS2013 x86):

```
target_link_libraries(youProj $ENV{OpenCV_DIR}/x86/vc12/staticlib/opencv_core248.lib)
```

Comment: This way I should add the lib one by one. I want to add the library by one variable